# Create a Map with Lists looping XML

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I have a requirement which i am not able to solve.

My XML looks like the below

```
<root>
<node1>
<value1>AA</value1>
<value2>123</value2>
</node1>
<node1>
<node2>
<value1>AA</value1>
<value2>999</value2>
</node2>
<node3>
<value1>AB</value1>
<value2>456</value2>
</node3>
<node4>
<value1>AB</value1>
<value2>888</value2>
</node4>
</root>
```

My requirement is to create a Map with all the value2's in it.

Output should look like the below
[AA:[123,999]]
[AB:[456,888]]

i am unable to approach this problem and need help or pointers please.I will need to check if the value1 field is different in the next iteration to the next node and store.

please help here.

Comment: What have you tried ? What errors are you getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @injecteer said.

Another way involves two steps but might be easier to comprehend:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def data = '''
<root>
<node1>
<value1>AA</value1>
<value2>123</value2>
</node1>
<node2>
<value1>AA</value1>
<value2>999</value2>
</node2>
<node3>
<value1>AB</value1>
<value2>456</value2>
</node3>
<node4>
<value1>AB</value1>
<value2>888</value2>
</node4>
</root>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)

def result = xml.'*'.groupBy { 
  it.value1 
}.collectEntries { k, v -> 
  [k, v.value2]
}

println result
```

which, when executed, prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
[AA:[123, 999], AB:[456, 888]]
```

where the first [`groupBy`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#groupBy(groovy.lang.Closure)) creates a `Map<String, List<xml node>>` where the keys are the `AA`, `AB` strings and the values are the xml nodes. The second [`collectEntries`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) operation pulls out `value2` from the nodes leaving the `result` variable as a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

<< edit >>

I realized this solution actually uses a really weird groovy "feature" where if you call `list.someProperty` and `someProperty` does not exist on the list class (like `java.util.ArrayList`), groovy will return a list with all the `someProperty` values from the list elements.

If we want to change this to not use that weirdness we can do:

```
def result = xml.'*'.groupBy { 
  it.value1 
}.collectEntries { k, v -> 
  [k, v*.value2]
}
```

instead which uses [the groovy spread operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator) instead of the undocumented weirdness.

Answer (score 2):

The code could look like:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def s = '''
<root>
<node1>
<value1>AA</value1>
<value2>123</value2>
</node1>

<node2>
<value1>AA</value1>
<value2>999</value2>
</node2>

<node3>
<value1>AB</value1>
<value2>456</value2>
</node3>

<node4>
<value1>AB</value1>
<value2>888</value2>
</node4>
</root>'''

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(s)

def result = xml.'*'.inject( [:].withDefault{ [] } ){ res, node ->
  res[ node.value1.text() ] << node.value2.text()
  res
}

assert result == [AA:['123', '999'], AB:['456', '888']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)

def result = xml.'*'.groupBy { 
  it.value1 
}.collectEntries { k, v -> 
  [k, v.value2]
}
```

this is definitely working.